# How can I generate dynamically an adwords commercial

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-ads-api

A user visited my website and performed a few actions. I want dynamically generate an adwords commercial depends on my CRM, when user will visit another sites.

How is it possible to do something like this:

1. The user visits another webstie
2. Adwords send to my service information about user id, which is stored in a cookie
3. My service dynamically generate HTML5 code
4. The code is presented in adwords box on the website

It should work like commercial from booking.com

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called DRM ([dynamic remarketing](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3124536?hl=en)). You've to create [Display Campaign](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201802/CampaignService.Campaign#advertisingchanneltype) on Adwords and then add HTML5 ads by adding targeting based on [Remarketing List](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201802/CampaignCriterionService.CriterionUserList) which is generated from your website's CRM data or directly from Google Advertising Pixel code.

Comment: It's looks great, is it possible to generate HTML5 ad which fit for only one user? I undersand, that I can generate one ad, next upload the code to the campaign, and then use adwords api, to show the ad for specific client. But it doesn't fit my idea. I want create neural network, which will create the ad "on demand" for single user. I don't want upload ad HTML5 code to the campaign, but I want generate it every user visit. Can I link/show content from my server into the HTML5 ad?

Comment: @juri96 HTML5 ads are template based ads, you can go to [Display Ad Builder](https://adwords.google.com/home/how-it-works/display-ads/) to go through [all display types of ads](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/templateads) which i think you can customise based on user.